# excel empty string formula

Tags: string, excel, formula

On Excel why putting a formula with the contents

```
=""
```

sometimes make the replacement for an empty string
and sometimes it places literally that text in the cell.

Note: every cell of the worksheet is in the text format.

Comment: you might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "Code Review").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the order in which you format the cell as text.

If the cell is not formatted as text, your formula will read ="" and the cell will be blank.

If the cell is formatted as text, your formula will read ="" and the cell will read =""

If you had the cell NOT formatted as text (number or general), entered ="" and THEN formatted the cell as text, your formula will read ="" and the cell will be blank.